# Dataset of Indian Address

Tags: address, large-datasets

I am looking for a dataset of Indian Address.
Possibly in the following format:
`Address Line 1`,
`Address Line 2`,
`Town/City`,
`State`,
`Postal code`.

I have tried to find it but there doesn't seem to be one freely available.
Has anyone tried point me to a spot where it may be available.

Comment: Did you check openstreetmaps.org?

Comment: Not sure what u mean, how can I generate random addresses on it?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were looking for a list of street addresses. If you download data from openstreetmaps.org you can parse that data for Indian addresses. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts might help. I believe what you're doing will require some work. I don't think there's a simple list anywhere, but I could be wrong. https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html to be even more specific